# Is it possible to "unstringify" __func__ in C?

Tags: c, vulkan

I'm trying to write Vulkan function wrapper macro that "generates" a typename of the style `PFN_vkCurrentFunction` automatically.

Pseudo-code example (doesn't compile):

```c
#define CALL(...)                                 \
  PFN_##__func__ functionPtr                      \
    = (PFN_##__func__) GetProcAddress(__func__);  \
  functionPtr( __VA_ARGS__ );

VKAPI_ATTR VkResult VKAPI_CALL vkCreateInstance(
  const VkInstanceCreateInfo*                 pCreateInfo,
  const VkAllocationCallbacks*                pAllocator,
  VkInstance*                                 pInstance)
{
  CALL( pCreateInfo, pAllocator, pInstance );
}
```

The `PFN_##__func__` part of this macro is invalid and will not compile.

Comment: Not in gcc, clang or tinycc, AFAIK.

Comment: Not sure if i understand your problem, but could `dlsym()` solve this problem? In C code at runtime, not in a macro.

Comment: Yes, I need to use `dlsym()` (or `GetProcAddress()` on Windows). But this doesn't the problem because `dlsym()` returns `void*`; I need to cast the result `(PFN_vkCreatekInstance)dlsym(h,"vkCreateInstance")` (where `PFN_vkCreateInstance` is the typedef of a function-pointer for `vkCreateInstance`). I need to load many functions with `dlsym()` so I'm trying to write a macro that will automatically spell this out for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to “unstringify” `__func__` in C?

No, it's not possible. C doesn't have reflection and `__func__` is not a macro, but it appears as-if declared by a `static const char __func__[]` declaration.

I would go with encompassing the whole function definition:

```
#define CALL(NAME, ...)                                 \
  PFN_##NAME functionPtr                      \
    = (PFN_##NAME) GetProcAddress(NAME);  \
  functionPtr( __VA_ARGS__ );

#define CALL_DECL_6(ret, name, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6) \
ret name(_1 _2, _3 _4, _5 _6) { \
    CALL(name, _2, _4, _6); \
}
#define CALL_DECL_N(_9,_8,_7,_6,_5,_4,_3,_2,_1,N,...) CALL_DECL_##N
#define CALL_DECL(ret, name, ...)  \
        CALL_DECL_N(__VA_ARGS__,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)(ret, name, __VA_ARGS__)

CALL_DECL(
   VKAPI_ATTR VkResult VKAPI_CALL, vkCreateInstance,
      const VkInstanceCreateInfo *, pCreateInfo,
      const VkAllocationCallbacks *, pAllocator,
      VkInstance *, pInstance
)
```

Comment: Good point with regards to `__func__` not being pp-token. But does this apply more generally to all real pp-tokens like `__FUNCTION__` or even string literals like `"vkCreateInstance"`?

Comment: `does this apply` What is "this"? `all real pp-tokens like __FUNCTION__` How is `__FUNCTION__` "real" pp-token? What is a "real pp-token" and how does it differ from...? "unreal pp-tokens"? `__FUNCTION__` is a gcc extension and it seems to be handled _by gcc_ the same way as `__func__` - it is _not_ expanded at preprocessor stage. `even string literals like "vkCreateInstance"` There is no possibility of removing `"` from a token once it has them. Preprocessor is a simple replacement, not string manipulation.

Comment: The rules are laid out by the standard, `__func__` is [an identifier (C11 6.4.3)](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.2.2p1), whereas [`__LINE__`, `__FILE__` are macros (C11 6.10.8.1)](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.8.1).

Comment: Your wording is unfortunate: of course `__func__` is a preprocessor token.  Perhaps you mean that it is not a macro identifier, or at least not one that expands to a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I can add an argument at the start and stringify it.
But I'm not satisfied with this solution, because I need to write out `vkCreateInstance` twice:

```c
#define STR(entry) #entry
#define CALL(entry, ...)                        \
  PFN_##entry functionPtr                       \
    = (PFN_##entry) GetProcAddress(STR(entry)); \
  functionPtr( __VA_ARGS__ );

VKAPI_ATTR VkResult VKAPI_CALL vkCreateInstance(
  const VkInstanceCreateInfo*                 pCreateInfo,
  const VkAllocationCallbacks*                pAllocator,
  VkInstance*                                 pInstance)
{
  CALL( vkCreateInstance, pCreateInfo, pAllocator, pInstance );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> Is it possible to “unstringify” `__func__` in C?

#### This is not possible in standard C.

Read for example the C11 standard draft [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), or the [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book, and see [this website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) about C.

#### but [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) like operating systems (e.g. Linux) have `dlopen` and `dlsym`

So read [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) (and also, on Linux [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [Advanced Linux Programming](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)). Look into my [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) example.

So perhaps try something inspired from

```
/// untested code...
void* progdlh = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW);
if (!progdlh) {
  fputs(dlerror(), stderr);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
};
void* funad = dlsym(progdlh, "some_function_name");
if (!funad) {
  fputs(dlerror(), stderr);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
VkAllocationCallbacks* cb = (VKAllocationCallBacks*)funad;
```

**Consider also using machine code generation libraries** such as [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/) or [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit) or [luajit](https://luajit.org/). You might generate some machine code at runtime (like [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/) does) to call your Vulkan code.

You could also generate some C code at runtime in `/tmp/generated.c`, and use [tinycc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler) or [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) (e.g. with [popen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) or [system(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)...) a [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) running `gcc -fPIC -shared -O /tmp/generated.c -o /tmp/generated-plugin.so` then `dlopen` that `/tmp/generated-plugin.so`. This has been done in the [CHARIOT](http://chariotproject.eu/) and [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) projects.

I took a Linux centered point of view. For Windows, study the [WinAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. In Vulkan, all API functions (e.g. `void vkFoo(int);`, `VkResult vkBar(const char*);`, ...) have a function pointer typedef that's prefixed with `PFN_` (e.g. `void (*PFN_vkFoo)(int)`, `VkResult (*PFN_vkBar)(const char*)`). I'm trying to write a macro that automatically spells out the `PFN_` typedef of the current function.

Comment: Il depends which programming language you are using. C does not have reflection abilities.